# OpenMP task directive slower multithreaded than singlethreaded

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I've encountered a problem where the task directive seems to slow down the execution time of the code the more threads I have. Now I have removed all of the unnecessary stuff from my code that isn't related to the problem since the problem still occurs even for this slimmed down piece of code that doesn't really do anything. But the general idea I have for this code is that I have the master thread generate tasks for all the other worker threads to execute.

```
#ifndef _REENTRANT 
#define _REENTRANT 
#endif 


#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <sched.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <sys/times.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <chrono>

#define MAXWORKERS 16

using namespace std;

int nbrThreads = MAXWORKERS;    //Number of threads

void busyWait() {
    for (int i=0; i < 999; i++){}
}

void generatePlacements() {
#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp master
    {
    int j = 0;
        while (j < 8*7*6*5*4*3*2) {
            #pragma omp task
            {
              busyWait();
            }
            j++;
        }
    }
}
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= MAXWORKERS; i++) {
        int nbrThreads = i;
        omp_set_num_threads(nbrThreads);
        auto begin = omp_get_wtime();
        generatePlacements();
        double elapsed;
        auto end = omp_get_wtime();
        auto diff = end - begin;
        cout << "Time taken for " << nbrThreads << " threads to execute was " << diff << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And I get the following output from running the program:

```
Time taken for 1 threads to execute was 0.0707005
Time taken for 2 threads to execute was 0.0375168
Time taken for 3 threads to execute was 0.0257982
Time taken for 4 threads to execute was 0.0234329
Time taken for 5 threads to execute was 0.0208451
Time taken for 6 threads to execute was 0.0288127
Time taken for 7 threads to execute was 0.0380352
Time taken for 8 threads to execute was 0.0403016
Time taken for 9 threads to execute was 0.0470985
Time taken for 10 threads to execute was 0.0539719
Time taken for 11 threads to execute was 0.0582986
Time taken for 12 threads to execute was 0.051923
Time taken for 13 threads to execute was 0.571846
Time taken for 14 threads to execute was 0.569011
Time taken for 15 threads to execute was 0.562491
Time taken for 16 threads to execute was 0.562118
```

Most notably was that from 6 threads on the time seems to get slower, and going from 12 threads to 13 threads seems to have the biggest performance hit, becoming whooping 10 times slower. Now I know that this issue revolves around the openMP task directive, since if I remove the busyWait() function the performance stays the same as seen above. But if I also remove the #pragma omp task header along with the busyWait() call I don't get any slowdown whatsoever, so the slowdown can't depend on the thread-creation. I have no clue what the problem here is.

Comment: C is not C++. Please don't spam tags.

Comment: Threads don't come for free, starting them up costs time. And so do synchronization actions between them. To really benefit from threads, you need to process enough data (while at the same time take CPU cache sizes in mind) per thread to be efficient

Comment: Do you perhaps have a CPU with 6cores and 12threads?

Comment: Since `void busyWait() {  for (int i=0; i < 999; i++){} }` will have no side effects the compiler will probably not generate any instructions for this. You really need to do some work to keep the threads busy. Side note : don't include `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`, do not use `using namespace std;` and define constants as `constexpr std::size_t MAXWORKERS{16ul}` not by using preprocessor macros.

Comment: Which compiler and compiler options do you use? On my laptop (g++ 12.2 -fopenmp -O3 options) 1 thread takes 0.0003s and the runtime increases with the number of threads.

Comment: @EyeBread Could you please address the questions in the comments (number of physical/logical cores on your machine, compiler version and options...)?

Comment: Yes, sorry been kinda busy! I have an AMD ryzen with 6 cores, 12 threads in total. My g++ compiler version is 11.3.0 (I think, don't have access to my stationary work computer atm so don't qoute me on that). I don't use any extra options during compile stage, other than obligatory ones such as "-fopenmp"

Comment: Thanks... This fully explains what you are observing. With more than 6 threads you are starting using the logical cores: sometimes it helps, but sometimes it hurts. Here it hurts. And above 12 threads, the threads are competing to access the cores. With latency-bound algorithms having more threads than cores can help, otherwise it hurts. Here it hurts. Also, to draw conclusions you need a busywait() with a higher workload, and compile with  `-O3` optimization turned on.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, the `for (int i=0; i < 999; i++){}` loop can be optimized by the compiler when **optimization flags** like `-O2` or `-O3` are enabled. In fact, mainstream compilers like Clang and GCC optimize it in `-O2`. Profiling non-optimized build is a wast of time and should never be done unless you have a very good reason to do that.

Assuming you enabled optimizations, the created task will be empty which means you are measuring the time to create many tasks. The thing is creating tasks is slow and creating many tasks doing nothing causes a **contention** making the creation even slower. The task granularity should be carefully tuned so not to put to much pressure on the OpenMP runtime. Assuming you did not enabled optimisations, then even a loop of 999 iterations is not enough for the runtime not to be under pressure (it should last less than 1 us on mainstream machines). **Tasks should last for at least few microseconds for the overhead not to be the main bottleneck**. On mainstream servers with a lot of cores, it should be at least dozens of microseconds. For the overhead to be negligible, tasks should last even longer. Task scheduling is powerful but expensive.

Due to the use of shared data structure protected with **atomics and locks** in OpenMP runtimes, the **contention tends to grows with the number of core**. On NUMA systems, it can be significantly higher when using multiple NUMA nodes due to **NUMA effects**. AMD processors with 16 cores are typically processors having multiple NUMA nodes. Using **SMT** (multiple hardware thread per physical core) does not significantly speed up this operation and adds more pressure to the OpenMP scheduler and the OS scheduler so it is generally not a good idea to use more threads than cores in this case (it can worth it when the task computational work can benefit from SMT, that is for *latency-bound* tasks for example, and when the overhead is small).

For more information about the overhead of mainstream OpenMP runtimes please consider reading [On the Impact of OpenMP Task Granularity](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01901806/file/iwomp_hal.pdf).

Comment: The busywait is a placeholder and I actually have a real function, I just added this to highlight the actual problem which is not related to my own function. So I don't think optimization has anything to do with it. I noticed that when I increased the task workload that it was then behaving correctly, but the issue still persists as when compared to using pthreads.

Comment: When using pthreads to parallize the same work, I notice speedup compared to this when increasing the cores. I skimmed over the paper you posted which seems to imply the case of the significant overhead bottlenecks the speedup. Is there another approach to parallize this kind of program without using openMP tasks? Where we generate these sorts of tasks in a while loop and simultaneously execute them? Or do we have to first generate all the tasks and then parallize using openMP?

Comment: Well, in this specific case, nothing prevent you to use a basic parallel for. Note that you should avoid using more threads than available core. If you do that then >=2 threads will run on the same core and this generally cause threads to be slower. This is dependent of the target operation : in some cases like in your example, mainstream processors can typically execute 2 threads doing half of the work faster than 1 threads doing the full work because of the dependency chain. This is why providing a realistic example is critical and providing the processor reference too.

Comment: Some OpenMP runtime do an active wait when they are starting for work to do. This is a problem when you use more than 1 thread/core. You can tune this behaviour with the environment variable `OMP_WAIT_POLICY`, but again, using more threads than core will cause a lot of issues and weird effects like this. Also note that parallel for loops have a `schedule` parameter useful to load balance the work if needed. Dynamic scheduling tends to be expensive so you need to care about the granularity again. You can try the `guided` schedule to start with.

Comment: Also note that it is generally better for N thread to produce their own bag of task in parallel if possible. This is generally faster because it is more cache-friendly and avoid any contention on shared data structure (assuming the runtime is properly implemented). Tasks can be executed on a different thread if a thread is starving resulting in a load balancing.

Comment: Do you have an example of threads producing their own bag of task in parallel to the tasks being created? What if the tasks are being consumed faster than the tasks are being created?

Comment: You just need to remove the `omp master` clause and distribute the work yourself. You can also combine this with an `omp for` so to not distribute things yourself. In fact, I m not convince of the usefulness of tasks in your example. When tasks are created in parallel, they are generally not produce faster than they are consumed. This is very unlikely and if this happens during a long time, then you have a serious design issue in your application. Some OpenMP runtime use a throttling strategy to prevent that (eg. GCC) as described in the above research paper.